# Classicthesis, drafting date persists

Tags: titles, classicthesis, date

I can not remove the drafting date from the title page of my thesis.

I am using classicthesis to write my thesis. I am not using the classigthesis-config.tex but define the package options directly when loading the classicthesis usepackage. 'drafting' is not included, but the date remains. I have used the 'search' function to search for 'draft' and 'drafting' in all files - there is none.

Please help me remove the draft date. Thank you in advance.

```
    \documentclass[twoside,11pt,a4paper,openright,footinclude=true,headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
eulerchapternumbers,
linedheaders,
%parts,
pdfspacing,
%dottedtoc,
listings,
eulermath,
subfig]
{classicthesis}

\title{
\Huge\textls[80]{\textsc{The letterspaced smallcaps look great}}\\
\vspace*{10 mm}
\large\textls[80]{\textsc{JANE DOE}}\\
\large\textls[80]{\textsc{PhD thesis $\cdot$ 2017}}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example just makes an error `! LaTeX Error: \l@subfigure undefined.` ?

Comment: do you just mean today's date in the title page? that is just the scrbook title, `\date{}` would make it empty

Comment: That solved it. Thank you - and sorry for the error MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date printed by `\maketitle` is not a result of a `draft` option. It is simple part of the default document title page. Its contents can be changed using the argument of command `\date`. So you can use eg `\date{<final date>}` or an empty date with `\date{}`.

But you are using `\title` to format the complet contents of the title page. So maybe it is better to use the `titlepage` environment instead `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[open=right,footinclude=true,headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
eulerchapternumbers,
linedheaders,
%parts,
pdfspacing,
%dottedtoc,
listings,
eulermath,
%subfig% would need one of the packages subcaption, subfig, ...
]
{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \usekomafont{title}\large%
    {\Huge\textls[80]{\textsc{The letterspaced smallcaps look great}}\par}%
    \vspace*{10 mm}%
    \textls[80]{\textsc{JANE DOE}}\par
    \textls[80]{\textsc{PhD thesis $\cdot$ 2017}}\par
    \vspace{\stretch{4.5}}%
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
Text
\end{document}
```

Note, that you can use `\cleardoublepage` to insert an empty even page after the title page.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The scrbook class you are using uses the date in the title you can make this empty using the standard latex command

```
\date{}
```